# Perl: Assigning an array to a hash

Tags: arrays, perl, syntax, hash

This syntax works:

```
$b{"x"} = [1,2,3];
pp %b;
# Displays ("x", [1, 2, 3])
```

But I need to be able to dynamically create the array's contents and assign it later.  This does not work; **help, what's the obvious part I'm missing**?

```
@a = [1,2,3];
$b{"x"} = @a;
pp %b;
# Shows up as ("x", 1) ... not what I want or expected.
```

Tried these variations, too.

```
$b{"x"} = [@a];  # ("x", [[1, 2, 3]])  ...close

$b{"x"} = \@a;   # ("x", [[1, 2, 3]])  

$b{"x"} = [\@a]; # ("x", [[[1, 2, 3]]])  

$b{"x"} = %a;    # ("x", 0)

$b{"x"} = $a;    # ("x", undef)

$b{"x"} = [$a];  # ("x", [undef])

$b{"x"} = @{@a};  # ("x", 0)
```

And, ideally, I'd like to be able to get the array back out later as an array.

Comment: My "pretty print" function came from CPAN -- use Data::Dump qq/pp/;

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The part you're missing is that `@a = [1,2,3]` doesn't make an array with 3 elements.  It makes an array with one element which is an arrayref.

You meant `@a = (1,2,3)`.

To assign that array to a hash element, you'd use either `$b{"x"} = [@a]` or `$b{"x"} = \@a`, depending on what you're trying to do.  `[@a]` makes a new arrayref containing a copy of the current contents of `@a`.  If the contents of `@a` change after that, it has no effect on `$b{x}`.

On the other hand, `\@a` gives you a reference to `@a` itself.  If you then change the contents of `@a`, that will be visible in `$b{x}` (and vice versa).

Comment: Thanks, I've been staring at the square brackets and seeing parenthesis.

Answer (score 18):

You need to read the [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html) documentation that talks about references.

There is a difference in how your arrays are stored:

```
# this is an array in an array variable
@a = (1, 2, 3);
```

Verses storing a **reference** to an array:

```
# this is an array in a scalar variable stored as a reference to the previous array:
$b = \@a;
```

Functionally that works like a pointer.  Thus you can also store this reference in a hash:

```
$x{'something'} = \@a;
```

This all works just fine.  What you haven't realized is that []s create **references** to an array, which you can't store in an array variable.  You must store it in a scalar.  Thus this instead:

```
$c = [1, 2, 3];
$x{'else'} = $c;
```

will work.

And accessing and modifying the array before you do the second assignment can be done using:

```
$c->[3] = '4';
```

or by using it in array form **dereferencing it first**

```
push @$c, 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example helped me with hashes. To end up in my code with:

```
# Following is confusing as hell. We look to store in the hash an array reference.
# But must convert back and fort via an scalar, since actual arrays returned 
# from an hash are copies in perl. i.e. my @a = $lists{$e}; will not work.

       my $a = $lists{$e};
       if(!$a){$a=();$lists{$e} = \@{$a};}
       push @{$a}, $v;
```

Thank you very much.
Will